# Passing a const char* to foo(char*)

Tags: c++, c

Whilst going through some c++ code as part of a PCI DSS certification review I came across the following:

I have a method in some library we use and one of its parameters is a char *, lets say this is

```
void foo(char* arg);
```

The point in the code where it calls this method looked like:

```
char mystring[256];
strcpy(mystring, "some value");
....
foo(mystring);
```

as part of the review we are getting rid of any strcpy calls (although in this example it is a bit trivial as the "some value" clearly fits in mystring)

So we get:

```
char mystring[256];
strncpy(mystring, "some value", sizeof(mystring));
mystring[sizeof(mystring)-1] = '\0';
....
foo(mystring);
```

This because I thought

```
foo("some value")
```

would pass a `const char *`

To my surprise however, the compiler (gcc 4) is quite happy with this. It doesn't even give any warnings when I add -Wall or  -Wcast-qual

My question is this: can I in this case safely call foo("some value") when I don't know what foo is actually doing (if anything) to its argument?

Comment: Please, please, *please* tell me you're not auditing a code base, and replacing `strcpy()` with `strncpy()`! *Especially* not if you're adding `sizeof` on the *source* string. Please, or I won't be able to sleep tonight. :|

Comment: @unwind I was just about to post the same comment. Do **not** do `strncpy(dest, src, sizeof src)`. You'r even better of letting `strcpy` be as is.

Comment: Commenters:  Justifications please!

Comment: I know the example is a bit contrived as I am using a string literal as a src, but please explain why I should not use strncpy instead of strcpy

Comment: This makes me never want to pay by card again. What do you think you're gaining by using `strncpy`  with the size of the source string? How is that safer than letting `strcpy` count the length of the string? What if the source string is longer than the destination? Why are you null-terminating the 255th char of `mystring`, when there are only 11 chars in the buffer?

Comment: @BenjaminLeinweber Isn't it obvious? `strncpy()` "works" by knowing the size of the destination buffer, so it can limit how many  characters it writes into said buffer. If you instead pass it the size of the *source*, that's not helping at all. Consider: `char buf[1]; strncpy(buf, "foobarbaz", 9);`, that will copy 9 characters (assuming there's no nul-byte) even though `buf` only has space for 1.

Comment: Simply: `src` can be of **any** size, now is that a guarantee it will fit into `dest`? **No.** You **must** of course not copy more data than the size of `dest`.

Comment: Hmm .. you are right of course .. I am glad that in this case it is my mistake of quickly re-phrasing a problem in a small example .. clearly we use the sizeof(dest) in the strncpy - I missed my mistake here - I edited the example above to reflect the problem I was really after -  thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::string` anyway and avoiding the issue? If you have to ask questions about how string literals work in C++ and can get the arguments to `strncpy` wrong, even in an example, then there is no excuse for not using `std::string`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it's not safe if you cannot guarantee foo won't modify the argument. Compilers can implicitly cast a string literal to `char *` for backwards compatibility with C code (unfortunately). You will have to copy the literal to a modifiable char buffer and pass that instead.

Comment: This conversion doesn't exist since C++11. String literals do not convert to `char*`.

Answer (score 9):

> Can I in this case safely call `foo("some value")` when I don't know what `foo` is actually doing (if anything) to its argument?

No. A string literal is constant, and attempting to modify it gives undefined behaviour.

For historical reasons, there is an obsolete conversion to a non-const `char*` which some compilers will allow - although that conversion is no longer valid since C++11. You should not rely on that, and hopefully you can turn up the warning level on your compiler to prevent it.

> To my surprise however, the compiler (gcc 4) is quite happy with this.

That is surprising. My GCC 4.6.3 gives a warning by default; I'd need to specify `-Wno-write-strings` to silence it.

Comment: The conversion _was_ deprecated, it's not valid in the current C++ standard.

Answer (score 2):

BTW, you're using `strncpy` wrong. The size parameter should be the size of the *destination* buffer minus one:

```
char mystring[256];
strncpy(mystring, "some value", 255);
mystring[255] = '\0';
```

The goal is to keep from overflowing the buffer.

Comment: I noticed & this was my mistake as I tried to rewrite my problem into a small example. We use the sizeof(dest) of course. Thanks

Comment: @Lieuwe Nope, you need `sizeof(dest)-1`. Also in C, gcc (or at least, early versions thereof) won't consider string literals `const` unless you give it the `-Wwrite-strings` warning specifier. No, it's not included in `-Wall -Wextra`, you have to specify it in addition to them. This warning is to be considered **indispensable** on all platforms that place string literals in read-only pages (that is, all modern ones).

Comment: gcc really needs `-Wseriously-all`.